# URLLoader or Loader in an AIR Worker in iOS kills the Worker, but Android is OK

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, loader, worker

I'm trying to offload image getting and processing to a Worker in an AIR/iOS app.  However, after calling loader.load(), the loader gets no further than the OPEN event.  Also, it will kill any Timers or Event.ENTER_FRAME listening, though the Worker's state reads as "running".

My code functions as expected in the AIR simulator *and* on an Android device (Galaxy S5), but dies in both the iOS simulator and on the device itself.  Below is trace output from my test app for each of the AIR Sim, iOS Sim, and an iPhone.  You will notice that for the iOS tests, it never gets to "complete".  I'm trying to load 4 images at the same time, but it also happens with just 1:

```
    AIR SIM Debug: (Works!)
    STARTING LOADER 0
    STARTING LOADER 1
    STARTING LOADER 2
    STARTING LOADER 3
    0 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    1 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    2 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,838 bytes after decompression
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,838 bytes after decompression
    2 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    0 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    1 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]


    iOS Simulator: (Broken!)
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,838 bytes after decompression
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,838 bytes after decompression
    STARTING LOADER 0
    STARTING LOADER 1
    STARTING LOADER 2
    STARTING LOADER 3
    0 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    1 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    2 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]


    iOS Debug: (Broken!)
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 835 bytes after decompression
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 835 bytes after decompression
    STARTING LOADER 0
    STARTING LOADER 1
    STARTING LOADER 2
    STARTING LOADER 3
    0 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    1 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    2 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]


    Android Debug: (Works!)
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,839 bytes after decompression
    [SWF] MultiLoaderWorkerTest.swf - 2,839 bytes after decompression
    STARTING LOADER 0
    STARTING LOADER 1
    STARTING LOADER 2
    STARTING LOADER 3
    1 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    0 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    2 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    3 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    2 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    1 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
    0 [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
```

My code is below.  I removed the PROGESS and HTTP_STATUS events for clarity in trace output, as neither iOS test ever gets that far anyway.

```js
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.MessageChannel;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;

    public class MultiLoaderWorkerTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var worker:Worker 
        private var primordialToWorker:MessageChannel;    
        private var workerToPrimordial:MessageChannel;    
        private var loaders:Vector.<Loader>;

        public function MultiLoaderWorkerTest()
        {
            if ( Worker.current.isPrimordial )
            {
                worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker( loaderInfo.bytes, true );
                primordialToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel( worker );
                workerToPrimordial = worker.createMessageChannel( Worker.current );
                worker.setSharedProperty( "primordialToWorker", primordialToWorker );
                worker.setSharedProperty( "workerToPrimordial", workerToPrimordial );

                workerToPrimordial.addEventListener( Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToPrimordial );

                worker.start();
            }
            else
            {
                loaders = new Vector.<Loader>();
                primordialToWorker = Worker.current.getSharedProperty( "primordialToWorker" );
                workerToPrimordial = Worker.current.getSharedProperty( "workerToPrimordial" );

                primordialToWorker.addEventListener( Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onPrimordialToWorker );

                workerToPrimordial.send( "READY" );
            }
        }

        private function onWorkerToPrimordial( e:Event ) : void
        {
            var msg:* = workerToPrimordial.receive();
            if ( msg == "READY" )
            {
                primordialToWorker.send( "GO" );
            }
        }

        private function onPrimordialToWorker( e:Event ) : void
        {
            var msg:* = primordialToWorker.receive();
            if ( msg == "GO" )
            {
                loadImage();
                loadImage();
                loadImage();
                loadImage();
            }
        }    

        private function loadImage() : void
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loaders.push( loader );

            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.OPEN, traceEvent );
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, traceEvent );
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, traceEvent );
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, traceEvent );

            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://www.thestar.com/content/dam/thestar/uploads/2014/6/26/1403815316554.jpg" );

            trace( "STARTING LOADER", loaders.indexOf( loader ) );
            loader.load( req );
        }

        private function traceEvent( e:Event ) : void
        {
            trace( loaders.indexOf( e.target.loader ), e.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to move your loadImage method and the logic to load images into an actual Worker class. Currently, there are only messages being transferred between your main class and your worker. 

I suspect that the loaders are being created on the main thread itself, as all you are doing is sending/receiving a message "GO" from the worker and loading things on the main thread itself. Try it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Alas, they are in the Worker class, and this is how to create Worker classes without loading a separate SWF.  Observe the Worker.current.isPrimordial test, which is true for "main" and false for the Worker.  The line, "worker.start()" is what creates the Worker.  Also, you're reading the signals in reverse; the Worker sends "READY" to the primordial, and then the primordial sends a "GO" to the Worker.

Comment: Ok you are correct, and I think creating a separate SWF could be a problem for mobile. Just doing my bit of research, and I am sure you've done yours as well, Are workers actually available for iOS?, I'm finding confusing information :(

Comment: Well, yes, I am able to use Workers, as you can see from my debug output from the iOS sim and device, but they collapse when trying to use either URLLoader or Loader.  In addition to not completing the Loader sequence, if I listen on Event.ENTER_FRAME or have a Timer running in the Worker, I will suddenly stop getting callbacks after I call loader.load().  Yet, the Worker still reports its state as "running".

Comment: Which version of Air are you using? 18.0.?.? (beta/release) or one of the 19.0.0.xxx betas?

Comment: @RobertN - 19 beta, 19.0.0.153, August 5th.  Sorry, should have mentioned that.  This is the latest build I can get, and I think the first release of Workers for iOS.

Comment: Do you see the same issue on the 18.0.0.209 (release)

Comment: @RobertN - I am trying it only just now, since (I think) Workers have come to iOS for the first time in this most recent release.  So, after your first question, I went ahead and built it for Android and, to my chagrin, it worked!  Awful!  Now I strongly suspect some underlying buggy bits on the iOS side.  I added to my question that it did work for Android, and included the debug output.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Adobe.  But, maybe it's just me!

Comment: Turns out it was a bug, and ostensibly has been fixed: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4033753